# Hypothesis testing a shift in a distribution's percentile profile

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test, ab-test

I ran an experiment introducing some changes to a service which *could* be slowing or fastening the service latency. The change was introduced with a treatment `T1` and `C` is the control. Each request to my service was assigned C or T1 with equal likelihood.

The insight I want to get from my data is - Due to factors introduced by treatment T1, is the distribution of the measurement changing (compared to C)? If yes, is it shifting from the lower percentiles to the higher percentiles, or is it shifting from the higher percentiles to lower percentiles?

I'm trying to compare the two distributions in terms of percentiles, using ideas outlined in this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4535814/

To summarize:

Say I have distributions for control and treatment - C and T1. My chosen percentile profile is 25th,50th,75th percentiles.

a) Find 25th,50th,75th percentile values of combined A+B distribution. Say the values come out to be x,y,z

b) Create bins `<x`, `>x and <y`, `>y and <z`, `>z`

c) Individually for A and B, find the distribution within above bins.

d) `Use Pearson’s chi-square statistic to test for homogeneity of the profiles of row percentages` - Quoting straight from the paper.

I don't understand the last step though. What does 'homogeneity of the profiles of row percentages' exactly mean?

eg. 
[image]
Here I'm using P10,P20,P30..P90 as my percentile profile. I calculated these percentiles on the combined population, created bins, calculated the number of measurements separately for C and T1 in each bin.

In context of this example, what does `Use Pearson’s chi-square statistic to test for homogeneity of the profiles of row percentages` mean?

I could consider the T1 array to be my observed values, and construct an expected values array which would contain SUM(T1)/10 in each of the 10 bins - and get an overall picture of whether or not T1 caused the distribution to 'shift' (with some level of certainty). Is it possible for me to tell whether it shifted 'upwards' or 'downwards'?

I'm a software developer dabbling in statistics to solve an interesting problem I'm facing - I've reached this point banking on my intuition and web search skills.